# How to configure Apache for Authentication

Tags: webserver, htaccess

i've got a Netgear Readynas 212 and I'm trying to set up a directory isting for a share.

Shares are located in /data/, where /data/share/ is the folder supposed to be listed.

On the NAS initial Share on web access is the /data/share/

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /data/share
    <Directory /data/share>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

With `a2ensite 000-default.conf` I've set the conf as default

Also Rewrite Engine with `a2enmod rewrite`

> .htaccess in /data/share

```
    # Apache Autoindex Directives
Options +Indexes 
IndexOptions ShowForbidden
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable SuppressRules ShowForbidden
IndexOptions IconsAreLinks ScanHTMLTitles NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=*

# Autoindex-Strapdown Directives
AddType text/plain .md
HeaderName HEADER.md
ReadmeName README.md

# Customize by setting theme and title
IndexHeadInsert "<script>conf = {theme: 'cyborg', title: 'Mitarbeiterverzeichnis'};</script> \
<script src='http://ais.habilis.net/autoindex_strapdown.js'></script> \
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ais.habilis.net/autoindex_strapdown.css'>"

# Icons using Bootstrap's Glyphicon set
DefaultIcon http://ais.habilis.net/icons/pdf.png
AddIcon https://10.0.1.222/icons/blank.png ^^BLANKICON^^
AddIcon https://10.0.1.222/icons/folder-open.svg ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon https://10.0.1.222/icons/back.png ..
AddIconByType (TXT,https://10.0.1.222/icons/file.svg) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,https://10.0.1.222/icons/picture.svg) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,https://10.0.1.222/icons/music.png) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,https://10.0.1.222/icons/film.png) video/*
```

**I've already downloaded icons and created a folder inside the listing share for them but still get the response .gif missing while debugging with the browser even though I've nowhere set those.**

[image]

I've also tried using [ramlmn's Directory Listing](https://github.com/ramlmn/Apache-Directory-Listing), no success.

Maybe someone has an idea what im missing

Comment: Are you asking how to set up authentication (per your question's title) or how to fix the missing images (per your question itself)? It's really not clear what you want help with

Comment: Current Problem is the Apache not properly reading the htaccess, I'm also looking for an alternative to be able to automatically redirect to Share based on user

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear what you're wanting help with. At the moment the first sentence says, "_I'm trying to set up a directory listing for a share_" and you talk about missing icons. There's nothing other than the title that has anything to do with authentication